# looking in applicatio main Views instead of Views of particular Area in MVC2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, controller, area

I am new to mvc2 application(asp.net 3.5 + sp1 + mvc2). I have created handler "HyphenatedRouteHandler" (by inhheriting MvcRouteHandler) to modify area, controller and action spellings.
Code:

```
public class HyphenatedRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (requestContext.RouteData.Values["area"]!=null)
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["area"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["area"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");

        requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");
        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

My direcctory stucture is as follows:
Areas
--Entertainment_Karmanuk
--Controllers
----Drama_NatakController.cs
--Models
--Views
----Drama_Natak
------Schedule_Timetable.aspx

It works fine if I don't use Area but when I use Area it searches view in outer main Views instead of views under view.. so it gives error:

The view 'Schedule_Timetable' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Drama_Natak/Schedule_Timetable.aspx
~/Views/Drama_Natak/Schedule_Timetable.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Schedule_Timetable.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Schedule_Timetable.ascx

Actually Drama_Natak/Schedule_Timetable.aspx is present in Area.

Am I missed something? Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `route.DataTokens["Area"]` value to the name of your area:

```
requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["Area"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["area"];
```